# Any other way to get access to kafka cluster with out broker address in sarama?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

Is there a way to start interacting with Kafka cluster in Sarama if broker address is not known?
If the broker which was used to connect with cluster goes down, how to reconnect?

Comment: What do you mean by interacting ? If you mean producing and consuming messages from kafka then it is not possible without broker address. Why do you want to avoid broker address? Can you elaborate please.

Comment: If you don't have a service discovery framework otherwise available, how do you interact with any external system? The people who setup the Kafka cluster should know the addresses

Comment: @RishabhSharma I just wanted to know, what if the node with broker address which we know goes down, In that case how do we reconnect. That was the reason, I was asking if there is another way to connect

Comment: @SaiPrakash That is why most libraries take comma separated list as broker addresses (and most probably sarama would support the same). So even if one of the brokers is down, the client moves on to another broker and continue processing (assuming conditions like replication, ISR are set correctly)